# AspxGridView initially load empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I asked this question here, too: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q388764.aspx
but I hope for a quicker answer here.

I need my grid to display data only after the user starts filtering.

This is the scenario:

1. When opening a page containing the grid, the grid should no even try to display the data.
2. When the user starts searching (applies a filter), the data should be displayed.

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q350421.aspx)
Subscribing to `DataBinding event` resolved all troubles with correct behavior actions like *sorting, filtering and groupping events* of ASPxGridView in runtime mode with requirement of getting DataTable for `ASPxGridView.DataSource`.

And you have answered at devexpress also it was also using the idea to implement this as i have looked by above reference link:

```
 protected void gvData_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["need_bind"]))
            gvData.DataSource = DSource;
        else
            gvData.DataSource = null;
    }
```

along this use `ASPxGridView.ProcessColumnAutoFilter` event handler

Answer (score 1):

Do not bind the data in the Page_load.

Bind the grid to the datasource in the filter event/ search button click event..

Answer (score 0):

Make the grid default to a filter that returns no records. The end user can then filter\search themselves and the ajax callbacks will repopulate the grid.